# my facet wrap produces two maps with data and one which just shows NA. How do I remove the NA map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I finally made a visualisation which shows my two points in time but it also produced a third map with only NA values. How do I get rid of this? I've attached my code and visualisation.

```
cases_and_CPI <- select(.data = COVID_dat, monthlyDateL, monthlyDateN, country, total_cases, ConsumerPriceIndicesGeneralAllItems_2010100, StayHome)
months_chosen <- c(2020.250, 2021.250)

StayHome_orders_April2020 <- filter(cases_and_CPI, !is.na(StayHome), monthlyDateL %in% months_chosen)

world_map <- map_data("world")

europeanUnion <- c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus",
                   "Czech Rep.", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France",
                   "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia",
                   "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland",
                   "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain",
                   "Sweden")
europe_map <- covid_map %>% filter(region %in% europeanUnion)

newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(newmap)
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-20, 59), ylim = c(35, 71), asp = 1)
Europe <- left_join(newmap, StayHome_orders_April2020, by = c(region = "country"))

europe_map$StayHomeFactor <- as.factor(europe_map$StayHome)

April_2020_StayHome_CPI <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = europe_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = ConsumerPriceIndicesGeneralAllItems_2010100, col = StayHomeFactor)) + 
  geom_path() 
April_2020_StayHome_CPI + facet_wrap(~monthlyDateL)
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `NA`s from your data. `europe_map = europe_map %>% filter(!is.na(monthlyDateL))`

Comment: I managed to remove it another way but thanks for the suggestion :)